# Which tecnologies would I need to send instructions from a web server to Raspberry PI connected to the internet

Tags: web-applications, raspberry-pi

I would like to create an RC car that uses Raspberry Pi as a brain and connect the Pi to the internet via 4g using a sim card.

I would be my final project for my bachelor's degree, and I'd like to research it further before troubling professors with it unprepared.

It would be controlled by a web application with user input being keyboard, gamepad and similar devices. Also the Pi would send back camera and maybe some telemetry, but it's optional, mostly interested in a camera stream.

I am adept at HTML, CSS and C#, but I am in the process of learning JavaScript.

So my question is rather which technologies should I learn to undertake such a project, where to start?

I've been doing some research and it appears AJAX would be the way to go but I'd like a different opinion if maybe there are other ways, or maybe questions similar to these that have been answered.

Thank you very much for any input.